# IntelliJ jBoss server log shows äöü with ??? on mac

Tags: macos, encoding, jboss, intellij-idea

When I start my Java EE  6 application in Eclipse everything is fine (all logs are ok).
When I now use the same application on exactly the same server BUT deployed and started with IntelliJ then the following logs

```
log.info("this is a test <äöüÄÖÜ>");
```

look like this

```
12:10:28,828 INFO  [...] this is a test <??????>
```

The source file as well as the project and general settings for file encoding in IntelliJ are set to UTF-8.

I'm using OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a wrong file encoding from jBoss. This could easily be set in Run Configuration under vm options with

```
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```